# input alphabet replace with numbers need solution

Tags: python, php, arrays

need help from experts
i am explain my problem in 2 steps  1st step am solved but 2nd step am confused

i want to replace input characters to numbers
i have one function split non english character from input and replace with powers numbers

```
here is my working function code step 1
$input="قیصر";    
$out = preg_split('//u', $input, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$output1=implode(',',$out );
```

now am run my code first step working perfect

```
 echo $output1
```

Result

```
  ق,ی,ص,ر
```

now i need solution from here i want to replace splited arabic alphabet replace with numbers

- ق replace with 1
- ی replace with 1
- ص replace with 9
- ر replace with 2

all replaced depands on inputs like this input have 4 arabic characters
so please
give me solution how to i replace splitid aplhabet with his numbers already defined

want to need output like this
**`1192`**

Comment: yes sir am add python because if any one have idea in python then share with us please

Answer (score 0):

```
$input="قیصر";    
$out = preg_split('//u', $input, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$output1=implode(',',$out );
$output1= str_replace("ق","1",$output1); #they're flipped because of arabic characters
$output1= str_replace("1","ی",$output1);
$output1= str_replace("9","ص",$output1);
$output1= str_replace("2","ر",$output1);
```

Comment: hello Petr here is static solution means only 4 characters but input values is randon my be 10 maybe 20   how i can danimically managed because arabic have 28 latters  every latter have different value asigened    how i can replace all random input values to numbers like you give me solution  for 4 alphabets  if  user enter 20 alphabets  how to replace brother danimically

Comment: @Qaiser420 The fastest way is indeed entering it like this. If you don't enter it like this, you'll enter it in a list - that's going to be a similar amount of typing

Comment: bro am testing your code but not working for me or please give me any example list array  if you give me am very thank full to you

Comment: Look at https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp

Comment: For Abjad numerals table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abjad_numerals#Letter_values